# Using vue.js, pinia, and pinia-orm

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, orm, pinia

1. Everything should be in two files:
   a. `start.html` for loading necessary libraries and loading `comp.js`.
   b. `comp.js` as a custom component with data.
2. `comp.js` should contain:
   a. Models with repositories:

   - `journal` (id, Name, Quantity)
   - `journal_line` (id, Journal_id, Name, Quantity)
     b. Loaded JSON data:
   - `journal` = [{"id": 1, "Name": "Journal01", "Quantity": 124}, {"id": 2, "Name": "Journal021", "Quantity": 0.15}, {"id": 3, "Name": "Journal03", "Quantity": 0}]
   - `journal_line` = [{"id": 1, "Journal_id": 1, "Name": "Journal line 10", "Quantity": 100}, {"id": 2, "Journal_id": 1, "Name": "Journal line 12", "Quantity": 20}, {"id": 3, "Journal_id": 1, "Name": "Journal line 13", "Quantity": 4}, {"id": 4, "Journal_id": 2, "Name": "Journal line 20", "Quantity": 0.1}, {"id": 5, "Journal_id": 2, "Name": "Journal line 21", "Quantity": 0.05}]
     c. Form (template):
   - Presented as two lists of rows with all fields.
   - All fields are editable.
   - The first list corresponds to `journal`, and the second one to `journal_line`. When selecting any field in the first list, the corresponding rows from `journal_line` are displayed in the second list.
     d. Reactivity of all data must be supported:
   - Data changes through the form.
   - Changes, additions, deletions through pinia-orm (from the browser console).
     e. Presence of triggers/hooks in the `journal_line` model:
   - Updating:

     1. In the changed object (before saving), change the `Quantity` field (`Quantity = Quantity + 1`).
     2. Output to the browser console log of the old object and the new object.
   - Creating:

     1. Output to the browser console log of the added object.
   - Global hook `delete` with output to the browser console of a deletion message and the deleted object.
     All hooks should trigger for both data manipulation via the Pinia-ORM API and through UI data changes.
     This is how the code works.

But my code is not working:
This is `comp.js`:

```
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import { createOrm } from 'pinia-orm';

const pinia = createPinia();
const orm = createOrm();

orm.defineModels({
    journal: {
        fields: ['id', 'Name', 'Quantity'],
        repositories: ['journalRepository'],
    },
    journal_line: {
        fields: ['id', 'Journal_id', 'Name', 'Quantity'],
        repositories: ['journalLineRepository'],
        hooks: {
            updating(oldItem, newItem) {
                if (newItem.Quantity !== oldItem.Quantity) {
                    console.log('Quantity updated:');
                    console.log('Old:', oldItem);
                    console.log('New:', newItem);
                }
            },
            creating(newItem) {
                console.log('New item created:');
                console.log(newItem);
            },
        },
    },
});

pinia.use(orm);

pinia.defineStore('JournalStore', {
    state: () => ({
        journal: [],
        journal_line: [],
    }),
    actions: {
        async loadInitialData() {
            this.journal = await this.$repo.journalRepository.all();
            this.journal_line = await this.$repo.journalLineRepository.all();
        },
        async updateJournal(newData) {
            await this.$repo.journalRepository.update(newData);
        },
        async updateJournalLine(newData) {
            await this.$repo.journalLineRepository.update(newData);
        },
        async addJournalLine(newItem) {
            await this.$repo.journalLineRepository.create(newItem);
        },
        async deleteJournalLine(id) {
            await this.$repo.journalLineRepository.delete(id);
        },
    },
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'my-component': {
            template: `
        <div>
          <h2>Journal</h2>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="item in $pinia.state.JournalStore.journal" :key="item.id">
              <input v-model="item.Name" />
              <input v-model="item.Quantity" />
              <button @click="updateJournal(item)">Save</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <h2>Journal Line</h2>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="item in $pinia.state.JournalStore.journal_line" :key="item.id">
              <input v-model="item.Name" />
              <input v-model="item.Quantity" />
              <button @click="updateJournalLine(item)">Save</button>
              <button @click="deleteJournalLine(item.id)">Delete</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      `,
            methods: {
                updateJournal(newData) {
                    this.$pinia.state.JournalStore.updateJournal(newData);
                },
                updateJournalLine(newData) {
                    this.$pinia.state.JournalStore.updateJournalLine(newData);
                },
                deleteJournalLine(id) {
                    this.$pinia.state.JournalStore.deleteJournalLine(id);
                },
            },
        },
    },
});

app.$pinia.state.JournalStore.loadInitialData();
```

And this is `start.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vue.js Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <my-component></my-component>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pinia@2.0.3/dist/pinia.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pinia-orm@0.5.0/dist/pinia-orm.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="comp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out the reason and how to fix it.

Comment: You're trying to use it as modular JS but you use regular scripts. Also you're using Vue 2.6 that is too old and may be incompatible. You'd have the same problem without orm. I'd suggest to stick to ready to use setup like Vite instead of fighting project-related problems

Comment: If I want to use Vue, what if I specifically need Vue and the mentioned modules for my project?

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/getting-started.html) paying special attention to the Vue 2 specific tips and instructions

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. You're using Vue in "CDN way", which is possible but is a less common way that isn't much documented. In the code above you'd need to remove `import` statements and use global variables for other packages (pinia and pinia-orm), similarly to how `Vue` is used, and you need to figure out yourself which variables this would be, often by browsing source code, because again, this isn't much documented. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation#CDN . Using build tool like Vue CLI or Vite allows you to stick to the common way of developing Vue app and follow the docs